# How do I use a js variable in a echo php function call?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

My actual application is to do content replacement from a db to an element id. I do it know from text files (1558 of them), and it works great. I* just wanted to try this method. Thank you ahead of time for

This attached code shows what I've tried. The echos in the php function show I make it into the function. The alerts show the sending values and return values work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var b = "MyText.txt";
</script>
</head>
</html>

<?php

function add($str){
    echo "My strtest file is : " . $str . " ";  
    echo  " ";
    $MyTexkFile =  "<html><head></head><div> <p> This is my html text display </p></div id = \'mydiv\'><body><body></html>";

    echo "The string is " . " " . $MyTexkFile . " ";    
    $newstr = $str . " Add some text to str";
//return $MyTexkFile ;
//return $str;
return $newstr;
}
?>
<script>
function phpadd(b) {
alert(b);
var a = "1234";
alert(a);
  var padd = '<?php echo add("3579.txt")?>';  
  console.log(padd );
}
</script>
<button onclick='phpadd("4567.txt")'>add</button>
```

As I said above, the code works properly until I try to pass a js variable (a or b). I've tried single and double quotes. With and without tilde.
My error: SyntaxError: '' literal not terminated before end of script jsToPhpFunction.php:15:97. Why is this? Can I do anything to get the variable to pass?

Comment: Pass `a` or `b` into what?  If you are trying to use a javascript variable in a php method, you cannot.  PHP runs on the server before the client gets the response.  Once the client gets the payload, it will then execute any javascript on the page, at which point it has zero direct access to the php

Comment: Javascript is client side, php is server side.

Comment: What you are trying to do will not work and it's not recommended.

Comment: You'll need to show the code that produces the error

Comment: Taplar, I understand you, however, as I said in my statement, if you look at the code, I have a quoted text value. Happens to be a text file name. as the call argument, Within the parenthesis. During run time, the echos, show that text file name makes it into the php function. And then with the console.log, the function return value makes back to the js script. I want ot know, if I can use that quoted text file name and see it work, Why can't I assign the quoted file name to var a or b and have it work?

Comment: Orangesandlemon, the code is above. The only difference, other than inserting the "3579.txt" in the php add() parenthesis , I want to use the js variable a or b with the same format or even the identical value. When I do, I get the error message I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry, I reference the error code. I did enter it a the time I wrote the question. I don't see it up there? Here it is : SyntaxError: '' literal not terminated before end of script jsToPhpFunction.php:15:97

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $str = $_POST['hiddenVal'];

  echo "My strtest file is : " . $str . " ";  
  echo  " ";
  $MyTexkFile =  "<html><head></head><div> <p> This is my html text display </p></div id = \'mydiv\'><body><body></html>";

  echo "The string is " . " " . $MyTexkFile . " ";    
  $newstr = $str . " Add some text to str";

}
?>
<script>
function phpadd(a) {
    document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = a;
}
</script>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="hiddenVal" style="display:none" id="hiddenVal" />
<button name="submit" onclick='phpadd("4567.txt")'>add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No Ralph, it's not what I wanted. The code does send a value to a php function and receives a value back from that function. No matter how many people say you can;t do that, that code does do just that. AlI asked, please enlighten me. What are the mechanics that allow me to manually  enter the quoted name of my text file into the parenthisis of the php function call and have it work properly.

Comment: Ralph, I apologize, your code does do exactly what I am trying to accomplish, thank you. But, it is not what I was asking as I said in my last comment.

Comment: @HalEgbert I'm afraid i've tried everything as well and was not able to input text as a function argument. I think you can edit the code and come up with a workaround because the way I see it don't think it's possible to do it directly.